# How to make an animation in SymPy using Matplotlib (Python)

Tags: python, matplotlib, sympy

**EDIT**

I will try to be more precise (above details have been removed because they are unnecessary):

**I want to make an animation where a (red) ball departs from (0,0) and draws the function sin(x). The function has to be drawn in blue, and the leading point has to be red (just as seen on the above pic)**

I have found a method to draw (animate) a function:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
xdata, ydata = [], []
ln, = plt.plot([], [], 'bo')

def init():
    ax.set_xlim(0, 2*np.pi)
    ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)
    return ln,

def update(frame):
    xdata.append(frame)
    ydata.append(np.sin(frame))
    ln.set_data(xdata, ydata)
    return ln,

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 128),
                    init_func=init, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

**My issue now is how to make the leading point red**

I've been told that I should create an empty list of the line elements and use the "append()" method to add new line elements, but I still don't get how to do so.

Reference https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/how-to-make-an-animation-in-sympy-using-python.969906/

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Add code instead of images, so it's easier to reproduce what you showed (and to improve it).

Comment: @David I did so. Anything else I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely, there are better ways:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

points = 50

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, points)
y = np.sin(x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(-0.3, 2 * np.pi + 0.3)
ax.set_ylim(-1.2, 1.2)

def animate(i):

    if i == 0:
#        fig.clear()
        ax.plot(x[i], y[i], 'ro')
    else:
#        fig.clear()
        ax.plot(x[i-1], y[i-1], 'bo')
        ax.plot(x[i], y[i], 'ro')

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=points, repeat=False, interval=150)

plt.show()
```